# Функция read() не считывает переменную из канала

Tags: c, unix

проблема заключается в следующем: в дочернем процессе я записываю при помощи функции write() переменную в канал, затем уже в родительском процессе хочу ее считать, но она остается неизменной. На скриншоте видно, что после записи переменная не равна нулю, но после считывания всегда равна нулю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n, k;
    int sum_C;
    int min_C = 0;
    int sum_R = 0;
    int min_R = 0;

    int fd[2];
    printf("Input n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Input k: ");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    printf("\nNumber of rows: n = %i\nNumber of columns: k = %i\n", n, k);
    int a[n][k];

    printf("\nMatrix A:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            a[i][j] = rand()%10;

        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            printf("%i ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(fork() == 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
                sum_R += a[i][j];
            }
            write(fd[1], &sum_R, sizeof(int));
            printf("\nAfter write: = %i\n", sum_R);
            return 0;
        }
        wait(0);
        read(fd[0],&sum_R,sizeof (int));
        printf("\nAfter read: = %i\n", sum_R);
        if (i == 0 || sum_R < min_R) {
            min_R = sum_R;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
           sum_C = 0;
           for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
               sum_C += a[j][i];
           }
           if (i == 0 || sum_C < min_C) {
               min_C = sum_C;
           }
        }
        printf("\nColumn sum: = %i\n", min_C);
        printf("\nRow sum: = %i\n", min_R);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка найдена, все было просто до глупости, я не открыл канал командой pipe(fd)